# Filtering by Date - Taking into Account the User's TimeZone

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I have a list of posts where posts has a "DateAdded" field which has been set to the UTC time. I need to filter the posts for a particular month/year. The part I'm struggling with is how I would take into a account the current user's time zone (including daylight saving time).

Here's the variables that needs to be considered:

```
List<Post> posts = ...;
TimeZoneInfo userTimeZone = ...;
int year = ...;
int month = ...;
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could show me the correct way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to convert the `DateTime` values of your query to UTC, and then filter on that.

```
// here are some posts
List<Post> posts = new List<Post>
{
    new Post {DateAdded = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)},
    new Post {DateAdded = new DateTime(2013, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)},
    new Post {DateAdded = new DateTime(2013, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)},
    new Post {DateAdded = new DateTime(2013, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)},
    new Post {DateAdded = new DateTime(2013, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)},
    new Post {DateAdded = new DateTime(2013, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)},
};

// And the parameters you requested
TimeZoneInfo userTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo
                                .FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
int year = 2013;
int month = 2;

// Let's get the start and end values in UTC.
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
DateTime startDateUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(startDate, userTimeZone);
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1);
DateTime endDateUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(endDate, userTimeZone);

// Filter the posts to those values.  Uses an inclusive start and exclusive end.
var filteredPosts = posts.Where(x => x.DateAdded >= startDateUtc &&
                                     x.DateAdded < endDateUtc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use C#'s `DateTime` class?  It should handle all this for you and it has a compare function?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx

It has multiple constructions depending on the degree of accuracy you know the time.

You can use LINQ to do the filtering of the `List`.

EDIT: For Timezone conversion http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769.aspx

Comment: And how does this at all address the OP's question about time zones?

Comment: Thanks but I know that much already. I'm asking how it can be done rather than what I need to do it.